# Is it correct to use one instance of ChromeDriverManager for all unittests

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, e2e-testing

I am using `ChromeDriverManager` for writing automation tests.
I am trying to figure out what is the correct way to initialize a driver for the tests.

Should I initialize one driver which should be used for **all** tests? 
Or should the driver be initialized for **each** test?

The cons of having a driver initialized for **each** test - is that it takes very long to initialize, if I have only one used for all tests, I save a lot of time. 
The cons of having **one** driver is that the cache may be saved, I could run `driver.delete_all_cookies()` but is that enough?

What is the recommended use?

In note: Currently the tests do not run in parallel, so there is no issue of having one driver, if in the future they will be ran in parallel, I can initialize a driver for each thread

**Option 1:** 
driver initialized for **each** test, using a fixture :

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def setup(request):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    request.cls.driver = driver

    yield
    driver.quit()
```

**Option 2:** 
one driver initialized and used for **all** tests

init_tests.py

conftest.py

```
myDriver = None

def pytest_configure(config):
    myDriver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())



def pytest_unconfigure(config):
    myDriver.quit

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def setup(request):
    request.cls.driver = myDriver

    yield
    myDriver.delete_all_cookies()
```

**test in option 1 and option 2:**

some_test.py

```
from init_tests import driver

class SomeTest(unittest.TestCase):


    def test_basic(self):
        driver.get('http://localhost:4001/login')
        # some testing
```

What is a more correct approch?

Comment: off the top of my head: there's browser cache which can be cleared via automating over browser settings, but ideally that shouldn't affect behavior and should help to speed up tests, there's stuff like localStorage and sessionStorage, which can be accessed via Javascript

Comment: yes, I prefer not to have browsing storage passing from one test to the the other. – 
I saw that for cleaning cache one can run `driver.get('chrome://settings/clearBrowserData')`,  but I'm wondering if using `driver.start_session()` before each test and `driver.close()` after each test should be enough